# Angular JS Slick Carousel - does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I have spent hours trying to reconcile 2 different directives with the Slick.js carousel.  I am currently using https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick

I have loaded the jquery version of the plugin as well as the angular part in index.html.  I've hooked up everything so that there are no js errors.

As per the more detailed jquery docs, I set up this:

```
<slick slides-to-show="1" slides-to-scroll="1">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>
</slick>
```

So, I see the first div and the nav buttons -- which do nothing.

What I really need to do is set up my own "next" button, so I added a button but can't figure out what the ng-click would be to go to the next slide.  According to the jQuery docs, it's `slickNext` so I have tried

`<button type="button" ng-click="slickNext">Next</button>`

or even

`<button type="button" ng-click="slick-next">Next</button>`

Nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by its [source code](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/blob/master/app/scripts/app.coffee). Pretty sure it's supposed to be

```
<slick ... next-arrow=".selector .to .next-button" prev-arrow=".selector .to .prev-button" >
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<button type="button" ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickNext()">Next</button>
```

and inside your controller, you need to specify slick to load via `slickConfig`, mainly as it uses this `method: {}` for it's functions under the hood.

```
   $scope.slickConfig = {
    autoplay: true,
    method: {},
    event: {
      beforeChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      },
      afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      }
    }
```